# Convert these fixed pixel widths to percentages

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I'm trying to convert these px widths to % but the results I'm getting don't seem to be correct.

My browser window is set to 1280px.

If the direct parent of this element I'm styling has a width of 968px (this is not set, this is being set via it's parent), I'm guessing to get the width of 270px in % I need to do 270/968? However if I change 270px to 27.892561983471% it actually ends up smaller.

Here is my original CSS with comments inline to what I think I should be calculating

```
.upper-search .query-input {
    font-family: Georgia, serif; margin: 0; 
    font-size: 1em; 
    line-height: 21px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    color: #4C4C4C;
    width: 270px; /* 270/968 */
    padding: 14px; /* 14/270 */
    height: 21px; 
    background: url( 'images/search-box.png' ) center top no-repeat;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think your calculations are correct they seem the same to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Fkp9Y/

Comment: Thanks @StefanV. I think the issue is that my .parent element doesn't have a set width